# Run laravel environment in docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm new in docker and I need you help. I want to start laravel in docker container. Which the best way for this? I don't want installed locally Composer, Laravel installer, PHP, or something like this. After some short googling I have found this article: https://medium.com/@shakyShane/laravel-docker-part-1-setup-for-development-e3daaefaf3c Please look it. All look like pretty good, but this tips don't works. I have this error. I understand this error. It's look like as I try to start Composer with old version of php.  [image]

Another guides suggest to have a lot of packages installed localy (Laravel installer, Composer and so on). 
So, this question is not about this error. This question is about, do you know some way for newbie that will be useful for understanding of this process. How you usually do it? Can you give me your short guide?

Comment: so you know whats wrong, and want a guide? PLease do a bit more work. The errors very clearly tell you what to do.

Comment: I am sorry, but I understand what does this error means and I don't understand how to solve this. Am I need to update php into composer container?

Comment: "requires php 7.1.3", so you should look in your docker-compose for php and change that to a higeher php version. Post your docker-compose.yml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting kinda states your problem
your PHP version does not comply with your Laravel version.

in your PHP dockerfile you see this:

```
FROM php:7.0.4-fpm
```

change it to

```
FROM php:7.1.3-fpm
```

that should do the trick

Comment: Thank you! It was old side repository of Composer. But this question about your way to run Laravel under docker. Tell me something about this.

Comment: I dont really know much about PHP or Laravel, but in the tutorial you followed I saw they where using an older version of PHP where the docker image was based upon, changing this should do the trick. Glad you got it sorted!.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak I wrote up an article about a simple approach to starting with Docker and Laravel, and write about Docker on Laravel News - This might help - https://bitpress.io/simple-approach-using-docker-with-php/